# Documenting Blender Python code with Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, blender

Blender runs its own Python. When I write Python code like this

```py
import bpy
print(bpy.data.objects)
```

for Blender it runs fine with

```
$ blender --background --python my_code.py
<bpy_collection[3], BlendDataObjects>
```

But when I want to document my code with Sphinx and the *autodoc* extension it cannot import `bpy` because it is unknown outside Blender.

```
$ cd doc/
$ make html
[...]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy'
```

How can I create documentation output for my Blender code with Sphinx?

Answer (score 1):

The solution involves modifying the Makefile generated by `sphinx-quickstart` as well as writing a little wrapper script around `sphinx.cmd.build`:

Replace the `SPHINXBUILD` variable in the Makefile:

```make
SPHINXBUILD = blender --background --python blender_sphinx.py --
```

and make sure that the actual recipe line at the end of the file contains the `-M` flag.

Then create a file `blender_sphinx.py` in the same directory as the Makefile with the following contents:

```py
import sys
from sphinx.cmd import build

first_sphinx_arg = sys.argv.index('-M')
build.make_main(sys.argv[first_sphinx_arg:])
```

Now if you run

```
$ make html
```

from the `doc/` directory it will allow *autodoc* to find `bpy` and import all the modules.

Comment: It is also possible to [build blender as a module](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) so that it is available in standard python.

Comment: Updated link here for [building blender as a module](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule).

Answer (score 0):

There's another option: Using a fake (i.e. empty) bpy module: https://github.com/nutti/fake-bpy-module

You can install this simply via pip:

```
pip install fake-bpy-module-<version>
```

Afterwards, your Sphinx (i.e. the Python build used by Sphinx) will import these modules instead of the blender modules.

Note: I'm not the author and I don't know how this module works with Blender's GPL license.